# access span in the from but undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I write something like this:

```
<form>
    <input>text</input>
    <div><span id="test">text</span></div>
.................
<button onclick="submitStudnetForm(this);"></button>
</form>

function submitStudnetForm(form){
    alert(form['test']);
}
```

but it return undefined, and I don't where is wrong?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Why do you expect `test` to be a property of the button element?

Comment: Just use `document.getElementById("test")`

Comment: Sorry, I confuse it....

Comment: `<input>text</input>` is wrong syntax. `<input type="text" value="text" name="the_text" />` is what you should put. And for `<button onclick="submitStudnetForm(this);"></button>` the parameter that'll be passed to `submitStudnetForm(elem)` will be the `<button>` not the `<form>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, `this` references the button rather than the form.  Even if it did reference the form, the form element only contains references to *input* elements by *name* (not by id).  You should use `document.getElementById('test')` instead.  This assumes that there is only *one* such span on the page as there should be because ids must be unique.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already said what I wanted to say. Also, is there a reason you're using a button with onclick to submit the form, rather than just input type="submit"? This way, users with javascript turned off won't be able to use that form.

(I can't insert this as a comment for some reason - I guess my reputation is too low for that?)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `this`, which is the button and you're trying to pull a property from it called `test`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Form is not an array (it's a reference to a button element in this case) with an index named 'test'. when referring to elements by id you should use `document.getElementById('test').`